# How to multiplicate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 1115 rows and 1 column and another with 18 rows and 1 column. I want to multiplicate them and obtain a dataframe with 1115 rows and 18 columns. I tried and I obtained a dataframe (1115x18) with `NaN` values.

This is what I tried to do:

A is the dataframe (1115x1)

```
A=pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(Mass*Per_RS))
```

```
               0
0     221.154473
1     -10.370921
2     203.945678
3      78.121608
4      78.121608
...          ...
1110  222.374772
1111  111.326855
1112  420.025814
1113  -87.408167
1114  158.834902
```

df is a dataframe with 18 rows and 100 columns. 'Reinforcing steel' is a column of the dataframe df (18X1)

```
0       2.20495
1   1.34068e-07
2     0.0477244
3     0.0109445
4   1.81331e-07
5   6.69694e-07
6   3.18976e-07
7     0.0110236
8   0.000229472
9    0.00208144
10    0.0247276
11      4.10829
12      10.0569
13     0.830528
14      23.6096
15  9.14322e-06
16      2.20263
17   0.00142633
18  0.000887094
```

My code is:

```
Results=(df['Reinforcing steel']).T*Per_RS
```

I obtain this (it works just for the frist column):

```
              0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
0     487.633639 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1     -22.867319 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2     449.689177 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3     172.253916 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4     172.253916 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
...          ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
1110  490.324331 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1111  245.469687 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1112  926.134175 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1113 -192.730275 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1114  350.222358 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  For instance, use a data frame of only 3 columns, not 18.  Your current posting suffers from formatting problems and lack of a clear specification of "multiplicate".  Give us a couple of examples of your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your problem with provided data. This sample could help you. `Results` have number of columns as dataset `df['Reinforcing steel']` and number of rows as dataset `A`.

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({"Mass*Per_RS": [
    221.154473,
    -10.370921,
    203.945678,
     78.121608,
     78.121608,
    222.374772,
    111.326855,
    420.025814,
    -87.408167,
    158.834902,
]})
df = pd.DataFrame({'Reinforcing steel': [  
    2.20495,
  1.34068e-07,
    0.0477244,
    0.0109445,
  1.81331e-07,
  6.69694e-07,
  3.18976e-07,
    0.0110236,
  0.000229472,
   0.00208144,
    0.0247276,
      4.10829,
      10.0569,
     0.830528,
      23.6096,
  9.14322e-06,
      2.20263,
   0.00142633,
  0.000887094
]})
Results = pd.DataFrame(A["Mass*Per_RS"].apply(lambda row: row * df['Reinforcing steel']))
Results
```

```
             0         1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10          11          12          13          14          15          16          17          18
0   487.634555  0.000030    10.554465   2.420425    0.000040    0.000148    0.000071    2.437918    0.050749    0.460320    5.468619    908.566710  2224.128420     183.674982  5221.368646     0.002022    487.121477  0.315439    0.196185
1   -22.867362  -0.000001   -0.494946   -0.113505   -0.000002   -0.000007   -0.000003   -0.114325   -0.002380   -0.021586   -0.256448   -42.606751  -104.299315     -8.613340   -244.853296     -0.000095   -22.843302  -0.014792   -0.009200
2   449.690023  0.000027    9.733185    2.232083    0.000037    0.000137    0.000065    2.248216    0.046800    0.424501    5.043087    837.867989  2051.061289     169.382596  4815.075879     0.001865    449.216869  0.290894    0.180919
3   172.254240  0.000010    3.728307    0.855002    0.000014    0.000052    0.000025    0.861181    0.017927    0.162605    1.931760    320.946221  785.661199  64.882183   1844.419916     0.000714    172.072997  0.111427    0.069301
4   172.254240  0.000010    3.728307    0.855002    0.000014    0.000052    0.000025    0.861181    0.017927    0.162605    1.931760    320.946221  785.661199  64.882183   1844.419916     0.000714    172.072997  0.111427    0.069301
5   490.325254  0.000030    10.612703   2.433781    0.000040    0.000149    0.000071    2.451371    0.051029    0.462860    5.498794    913.580052  2236.400845     184.688475  5250.179417     0.002033    489.809344  0.317180    0.197267
6   245.470149  0.000015    5.313007    1.218417    0.000020    0.000075    0.000036    1.227223    0.025546    0.231720    2.752846    457.363005  1119.603048     92.460070   2628.382516     0.001018    245.211871  0.158789    0.098757
7   926.135919  0.000056    20.045480   4.596973    0.000076    0.000281    0.000134    4.630197    0.096384    0.874259    10.386230   1725.587851     4224.157609     348.843199  9916.641458     0.003840    925.161459  0.599095    0.372602
8   -192.730638     -0.000012   -4.171502   -0.956639   -0.000016   -0.000059   -0.000028   -0.963553   -0.020058   -0.181935   -2.161394   -359.098098     -879.055195     -72.594930  -2063.671860    -0.000799   -192.527851     -0.124673   -0.077539
9   350.223017  0.000021    7.580300    1.738369    0.000029    0.000106    0.000051    1.750932    0.036448    0.330605    3.927606    652.539840  1597.386726     131.916833  3750.028502     0.001452    349.854520  0.226551    0.140901
```